# Read large json file in PHP

Tags: php, json, large-data

I'm using this code to load a large json file which make my website very slow.

Is there any other way to read large json files and keep my website fast?

```php
$json = file_get_contents($pathToFile);
$json_data = json_decode($json, true);
```

Comment: How large is the file? Do you need the full file?

Comment: Are you sure this is the bottleneck?

Comment: @user3783243 i have many files each with 10Mo

Comment: @nice_dev not sure, i know the performance of my server is related to the problem but i want to find out if there is any way to make my website faster by changing code